# Can a AWS Lambda Subscribe to Multiple Event Source Types

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-kinesis

Two questions:

1. Is it possible for a lambda to subscribe to a kinesis topic and an SNS topic? For example, your handler method is defined as: `public void handleRequest(Object obj, Context cxt)`. Would it then be possible to cast `obj` into a `KinesisEvent` or `SNSEvent`?
2. If I wanted all instances of a lambda to receive some update, would SNS be appropriate for that? For example, I want all instances of a lambda to update its cache (ElastiCache is not applicable for our use case) against a database.

Thanks for all responses!

Comment: On #1, yes, a given Lambda function can be the target for multiple event sources. Personally, if I were going to do that, I would configure different entrypoints (methods) within the Lambda function, one per event source type. On #2, what do you mean by "all instances of a lambda". Lambda functions are transient.

Comment: Thanks for the response @jarmod. For (2), let me re-frame the issue. If I have variable outside the handler, will all lambda invocations (suppose AWS scales up instances) see the same variable state in memory?

Comment: A warm-started Lambda function invocation will see the same state (global variables and /tmp diskspace) as were present at the end of the previous invocation. But, in the general case, no, variable values will not persist. Note that if N Lambda invocations happen concurrently then they are all using different runtime environments so it would be impossible for them to all share the state of a single prior invocation. See [container reuse](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/).

Comment: So, suppose there's a single container handling all invocations, where I have a global variable serving as a cache. If AWS scales up my lambda and creates a new container, then it's possible (if not guaranteed) that variable state won't be transferred to the new container?

Comment: There isn't typically a single runtime environment handling all invocations. If you happen to serially invoke a Lambda function and each N'th invocation ends before the N+1'th invocation happens then that might result in a single runtime environment being reused again and again. If AWS launches a new runtime environment (the 'cold start') then it's guaranteed to be clean and will not contain any state from a prior runtime invocation.